# Http hear request into Keystone

Tags: http-headers, keystone, webscarab

I want to take token from keystone and examine them by getting a lot of them.

I already got one token by using REST API as:

[image: REST API]

Now I want to get a lot of token so I using Webscarab application as:

[image: picture2]

but I don't know which header I need to provide.
I try to put:

> Content-Type: application/json
> id_username: (myusername)
> id_password: (mypassword)

but failed.

Anyone know that, please help me.

Comment: Would be the provider of your service which can answer what headers are required

Comment: Thanks for reply. the service is keystone. everytime authenticate with keystone, user will get the token via http header.